# How do I use torch.profiler.profile without a context manager?

Tags: python, pytorch, profiler, torchvision, autograd

In the [pytorch autograd profiler documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#profiler), it says that the profiler is a "Context manager that manages autograd profiler state and holds a summary of results." However, in a [different part of the documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/tensorboard_profiler_tutorial.html#use-profiler-to-record-execution-events) it demonstrates a non-context manager start/stop which it says is also supported. However, in torch 1.9.0 it appears this start/stop alternative has been removed:

```
from torch.profiler import profile
prof = profile()
prof.start()
# --> AttributeError: 'profile' object has no attribute 'start'
```

I have looked into step() instead, but that also does not work (it does not initialize the profiler).

The use case is that I would like to profile the training run without needing to edit the code which actually calls the training script: I have access to the state before and after, but not the exact training script.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the pytorch version you are using. You need to select the correct docs for your pytorch version. Older versions don't seem to have the `start()` member function.

Check the difference between these two:

Version 1.13
https://pytorch.org/docs/1.13/_modules/torch/profiler/profiler.html#profile

Version 1.8.1
https://pytorch.org/docs/1.8.1/_modules/torch/profiler/profiler.html#profile